# Virtual Host s not working for second URL

Tags: apache-2.2

SO I am hosting a couple sites on the same server. The first url point to the right folder but the second and the third for that matter, I get the intial Apache test pages. Can anyone tell why that is happening. I do have `NameVirtualHost *:80` in my config file. I also have followed the Apache documentation.

```
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/Dev
ServerName www.scsdeveloper.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/Pro/zenchi
ServerName www.zenchi.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/Pro/zenchi
ServerName www.zenchipillow.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you have apache reread the config after editing it?

Comment: @JennyD I had it restart the service would that make it reread?

Comment: Yes, that does it. Just checking because it's surprisingly often the answer to this type of question!

Comment: Btw, kudos for using your actual domain names! It makes it a **lot** easier to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try those sites I get the Wordpress setup page. Could it be as simple as your web browser having previous responses cached?

When I want to verify for certain what a web server does, I use telnet - like this:

```
ryo-ohki:~ jenny$ telnet www.zenchi.com 80
Trying 75.101.150.236...
Connected to zenchi.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.zenchi.com       

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 18:00:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Amazon)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20
Location: http://www.zenchi.com/wp-admin/install.php
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As you see, what I get is a redirect to the Wordpress install page, not the default Apache "server is working" page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://alexking.org/blog/2007/11/01/apache-2-only-serves-first-virtual-host

Simply add the following at the top of your file:
NameVirtualHost *:80

It worked for me !

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.